# Is MySQl replication the best solution for me?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have eight master servers dbs that are operating on identical databases on a localhost webapp to register payments as by my client specs

I need to replicate all these to a slave or replica which is our main server

But master slaves have internet and power outages constantly so there will be no reliable connection

The end goal is to have access to the data in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer to your question is "no". Replication has one primary server that is replicated by secondary databases, not the other way around. I that case, the primary is the only one that gets written to, so there are not any conflicts.

If you have a system where many databases are being modified, then you will need a way to reconcile the changes later. Two of your distributed databases could have inserted a row with the same id, for instance.

You probably want to use UUID's for all your id columns, and you're going to have to write code that does the reconciliation, or use a database product that supports `eventual consistency` (all of which, as far as I know, use UUID's).

Edit to add: unless your database is super-simple, you are going to find reconciling the versions to be really tricky. What if two people edit the same record? Who's version wins? What if they only edit different columns?

Unless your users are carefully siloed on what information they can change, I'd advise leaving the reconciliation process to the professionals.